# Doctrine : advantages/drawback of a bidirectional relation

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I just want to know what are advantages/drawback of a bidirectional relation in Doctrine with Symfony ?

All my relations are bidirectional, but I'm not sure if this will not cause a problem...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't mark relations as `EAGER` I think you're good. to go.

However, there is a small overhead since `PHP` has to, at least, create `Proxy` instances. Beware of this if you plan on serializing objects. Some serialization mechanism are programmed to resolve (load) proxy if they hit one. That would mean an extra round-trip to database server.

Bottom line: As you develop your model, ask yourself "Do I really need this?". It's super easy to add it later if you find yourself in that situation. Also, when it comes to `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`, pay special attention to `owning`/`inverse` side concepts as it could introduce a number of WTFs/minute :)

Hope this helps you a bit...

Comment: Also, consider mentioning extra caution with many-to-many relations, since doctrine handle the "mid table" by itself.
This can cause a high number of WTFs/minute too!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I created this type of relations with the approach 'maybe I will have to do this later' but you're right, the only question useful must be 'Do I really need this'. I change it for unidirectionnal relations :)

Comment: For example, I find it very useful to introduce bidir side of relation when I work with forms... :)